# jigsaw puzzle source image is not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying jigsaw puzzle using kineticJs. I got the irregular shape pieces but source image is not displayed or fill in it. I'm stuck with this part.

```
fill:{
    image:imageObj,
    x:pieceWidth,
    y:pieceHeight,
},
stroke: "#000000",
strokeWidth: 4,
lineCap: "round",
draggable: true
```

Comment: You need to show more code because we can't tell what you're doing...And `fill:{ image:imageObj, x:pieceWidth, y:pieceHeight,},` is not valid KineticJS syntax. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `fillPatternImage` instead of `fill`.

```
var patternPentagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
      x: 220,
      y: stage.height()/2,
      sides: 5,
      radius: 70,
      fillPatternImage: images.darthVader,
      fillPatternOffset: {x:-220, y:70},
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 4,
      draggable: true
});
```